# ¿Es posible instalar SQL Server al momento de instalar mi aplicación?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¡Hola!

Soy algo nuevo en este mundo, y lo que pasa es que tengo una duda algo básica:

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en java para un cliente, misma que utilizará SQL Server. Quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de que al mi cliente instale la aplicación en su equipo, se instale SQL Server en su equipo con la misma configuración que yo la tengo en mi equipo (hablando sobre su respectiva base de datos)

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: antes de entrar en si se puede o no, es conveniente que se verifique el tema de licencias, SQL Server tiene varios productos y diferentes licencias (y coste $$) por cada una. En primera instancia si el cliente requiere que sea SQL Server el deberia proveer el motor de base de datos (normalmente ya se debe terner), de otra parte SQL Server tiene una versión que creo se llama `local` la cual se embebe dentro de la aplicación que se esta desarrollando, similar a `SQLite`o a `derby`

Comment: La conexión a la base de datos no debería ser remota?

Comment: Licencias. El cliente debe revisar los términos de uso y costos de las diferentes versiones de SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes instalar una versión express gratuita en cualquier cliente sin ningún problema.

[Sql server express](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)

[Derechos de uso](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29693)

La limitación de esta viene dada por procesamiento (1 core), tamaño (10Gb) y Ram (1Gb), a grandes rasgos. Puedes consultar la documentación al efecto. Para cualquier cliente cuya gestión de usuarios ***concurrentes***, no sea muy grande, y cuya cantidad de datos, no sea gigantesca, es suficiente. Cualquier pyme, puede trabajar con las ediciones express y no se entera. Si necesita más requerimientos, luego se puede pasar a una edición estandar sin cambios en el aplicativo.

[Caracteristicas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15)

La dificultad es que tendrás que realizar una instalación del sql server, y para eso, o utilizas una aplicación desarrollada como installShield (al menos en punto net), o utilizas la instalación silenciosa. Te dejo dos enlaces que pueden serte útiles.

[Instalación silecionsa MS-SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Instalación desatendida](https://blogs.solidq.com/es/sql-server/instalacion-desatendida-de-sql-server-express/)